# Django return distinct images

Tags: python, django

- I have a 3 x 3 grid and I am trying to return randomly selected images that are distinct from a given directory.
- I am currently getting images as an output but some of them are repeated.
- There are a total of 10 images in the directory, all numerically named.
- Screenshot of Current output:
  [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqt4R.png)

---

**What should I do to get distinct images as my output?**

P.S: I am new to Django so any any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**random_Image.py** - *Template tag returning a list of selected images*

```
@register.simple_tag
def random_image(image_dir):
    valid_extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif']
    rand_dir = '/static/app_pickfeel/images/'
    # print(rand_dir)
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(settings.BASE_DIR + '/app_pickfeel/static/app_pickfeel/images')
             if f[f.rfind("."):len(f)] in valid_extensions]

    remove_duplicate = set(files)
    final_list = list(remove_duplicate)

    return rand_dir + random.choice(final_list)
```

**random_Image.py: Output for 'files'**

```
{'2.gif', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '1.jpg', '9.jpg', '8.jpg', '4.jpg', '7.jpeg', '3.jpg'}
{'2.gif', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '1.jpg', '9.jpg', '8.jpg', '4.jpg', '7.jpeg', '3.jpg'}
{'2.gif', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '1.jpg', '9.jpg', '8.jpg', '4.jpg', '7.jpeg', '3.jpg'}
{'2.gif', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '1.jpg', '9.jpg', '8.jpg', '4.jpg', '7.jpeg', '3.jpg'}
{'2.gif', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '1.jpg', '9.jpg', '8.jpg', '4.jpg', '7.jpeg', '3.jpg'}
{'2.gif', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '1.jpg', '9.jpg', '8.jpg', '4.jpg', '7.jpeg', '3.jpg'}
{'2.gif', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '1.jpg', '9.jpg', '8.jpg', '4.jpg', '7.jpeg', '3.jpg'}
{'2.gif', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '1.jpg', '9.jpg', '8.jpg', '4.jpg', '7.jpeg', '3.jpg'}
{'2.gif', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '1.jpg', '9.jpg', '8.jpg', '4.jpg', '7.jpeg', '3.jpg'}
```

**random_Image.py - Output for 'random.choice(final_list)'**

```
1.jpg
3.jpg
2.gif
6.jpg
9.jpg
9.jpg
7.jpeg
2.gif
8.jpg
8.jpg
1.jpg
7.jpeg
3.jpg
```

---

**pickfeel.html** - *Where the template tag is used (Shown is Row 1, there are 3 rows in total)

```
<!--Row 1-->
        <div class="row no-pad display-flex  my-row">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col-xl-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 my-col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col-sm-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col- my-col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{% random_image 'app_pickfeel/images/' %}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col my-col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 my-col">
                 <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{% random_image 'app_pickfeel/images/' %}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col my-col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 my-col">
                 <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{% random_image 'app_pickfeel/images/' %}">
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

**views.py**

```
def pickfeelhome(request):

    context = {}

    return render(request, 'app_pickfeel/pickfeel.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to your tag will select one random image out of the ten existing ones. Those calls being totally independent, the tag's code cannot know which image has been returned by a previous call (nor even if there has been any previous call).

The easiest solution is to make your tag return a list of images, store this list in a templatevar and then iterate on it:

```
@register.simple_tag
def random_images(count=3):
    valid_extensions = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')
    # NB: 
    # 1. you should use `os.path.join()` to create your file path
    # 2. you shoudn't hard code this path
    # 3. `f[f.rfind("."):len(f)]` can be simplified as `f[f.rfind("."):]`
    # ... and well, there are other ugly things, but anyway ;-)

    files = [f for f in os.listdir(settings.BASE_DIR + '/app_pickfeel/static/app_pickfeel/images')
             if f[f.rfind("."):len(f)] in valid_extensions]

    # this is useless, you won't have duplicates in a directory file listing
    # (file names are unique within a directory)

    return [rand_dir + filename for filename in random.sample(files, count)]
```

And then

```
    {% random_images 3 as images %}
    <div class="row no-pad display-flex  my-row">
        {% for image in images %}
        <div class="....">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{ image }}">
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: That's great, thank you so much for your help and detailed response.